# SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: debian, ssl, debian-lenny, certificate-authority

I'm running Debian (Lenny).

When I run this:

```
curl --ssl https://www.google.com
```

I get this error:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Comment: There's a link in that error message that tells you to go read something, have you read it?  Have you read the rest of the message under that link?  Have you taken the actions those two resources instructed you to? (If the answer to that last questions was "yes" you probably wouldn't be getting this error anymore -- if the answer is *honestly* yes and you're *still* getting this error tell us which steps you've taken to make it go away, and let me know so I can re-open this question and we'll try to help you out :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might happen because curl can't access valid CA certs bundle. Maybe you just didn't install those, so try this:

```
apt-get install ca-certificates
```

If it doesn't help - check `CURL_CA_BUNDLE`, make sure curl doesn't look for bundle in a wrong place.

Comment: yep, did both. I think it was the latter that did it. thanks!

Comment: Checking the `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` also worked for me, somehow I had this line in my `.profile`: `export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=~/.ssh/cacert.pem`. Maybe I added it a while ago for debugging/development. Removing it fixed my problem.